# what is convention of creating JAVA class from ERD?

Tags: java, oop

I`m implementing an Android app .
I have some entities in Model layer , at this time 2 entities are are subject of my discussion .
*STUDENT* and *EDUCATION* . So every student has one or more education.

Now, my question is how should I create their JAVA classes?
Should I create a Student java class same as :

```
class Student{
   private int id;
   private List<Education> educations;
}
```

Or should I create an Education JAVA class same as :

```
class Education{
  private String cod;
  private String des;
  private Student student;
}
```

which solution is correct?

Thanks.

Comment: If you have a `STUDENT` entity, why do you create a `User` class, not a `Student` class? --- Why couldn't both solutions be correct at the same time? If you need to **navigate** in both directions at runtime, you'll probably want them to relate to each other. But it entirely depends on what you need at runtime, either or both can be the correct solution.

Comment: Also, aren't Educations shared? Can't multiple Students have the same Education? So, isn't this a many-to-many association?

Comment: Thank Andreas.each Education is related to one Student.

Comment: That means you'll probably never need to navigate from Education to Student at runtime, but you'll need the list of Educations a Student has, right? Doesn't that answer the question?

Comment: I recommend the Head first OOA &D book.